# Vuetify how to add props to v-list-group v-slot:activator template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Im attempting to make a similar menu to the [expansion lists](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#expansion-lists) example in the documentation . This uses the v-list-group and v-slot:activator components. Each of the child elements have a child list-item, which is easy to add a vue-router link to. The issue is that when one of the parent list items (Dashboard) dont have children items, i wish to add a vue-router `:to` link instead to this, although these parent list-items use the v-slot:activator template and im unsure how i can add props or events to this.

I read about the v-slot activator here [github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6866), but it doesnt seem to mension how I can achieve what i need it to do.

**Template**

```
    <v-list>
        <v-list-group
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.name"
            v-model="item.active"
            :prepend-icon="item.icon"
            :append-icon="item.children ? undefined : ''"
            no-action
        >
            //Want this to work with :to or @click
            <template v-slot:activator :to="{name: item.route}">
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </template>

            <v-list-item
                v-for="childItem in item.children"
                :key="childItem.name"
                :to="{name:childItem.route}"
            >
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title v-text="childItem.name"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
```

**Data**

```
     items: [
                {
                    name: 'Dashboard',
                    route: 'dashboard',
                    active: false,
                    icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Editor',
                    icon: 'mdi-pencil',
                    active: false,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'General',
                            route: 'general',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Designs',
                            route: 'designs',

                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Images',
                            route: 'images',
                        },
                    ],
                },
          ];
```

---

### Update

I hacked together a workaround by adding v-list-item inside the template when the parent element contains a route key. Then using absolute position to extended its size to fit the parent template. Am i missing something...is this the best method of achieving this?

```
    <template v-slot:activator>
        <v-list-item v-if="item.route" :to="{name: item.route}" class="item-link"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
```

**Style**

```
 .item-link {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer, but, I had the same issue and found a workaround using the slot attribute. (NOT THE V-SLOT in the template) - remove the template, here check it out:

```
<v-list-group v-for="(parentCat, parent_id) in item.parent_cat" :key="`${parent_id}parentCat`" :value="openParent==parent_id" append-icon="" active-class="tagActiveIcon" @click="parentCatChanged(parent_id)" :disabled="true">
    <div slot="activator" class="d-flex justify-space-between maximizeWidth" @click="parentCatChanged(parent_id)">
        <div>Par_{{ parentCat.title}}</div>
        <div><v-icon color="primary">mdi-eye</v-icon></div>
    </div>
...
```